# Modify Excel Cell Value on Button Click Apache POI & JavaFX

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I am trying to write a simple program that create a small application that, on button click will write a value to an excel spreadsheet.

In the code below, the program will write the value 25 to the cell and then print "25.0". Then it will write 50 to the cell on button click and print out "50.0", but once I close the application and open the spreadsheet the value 25 is displayed inside the cell.

```
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;


public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    XSSFWorkbook schedule = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet firstSheet = schedule.createSheet("Dis a sheet");
    XSSFRow firstRow = firstSheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell firstCell = firstRow.createCell(0);
    firstCell.setCellValue(25);
    System.out.println(firstCell.getRawValue());

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            writeInfoToCell(firstCell,50);
            System.out.println(firstCell.getRawValue());
        }

    });

    //});
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("schedule.xlsx"));
    schedule.write(out);
    out.close();
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
public void writeInfoToCell(XSSFCell cell, int information){
    cell.setCellValue(information);
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? It has to be something with the clicking of the button, because if I remove the button entirely, the value is written to the cell correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your btn action only writes to the `XSSFCell` but you're not writing to the `XSSFWorkbook`.

Try:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("schedule.xlsx"));                 
            writeInfoToCell(firstCell,50);
            System.out.println(firstCell.getRawValue());
            schedule.write(out);
            out.close();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? It has to do with the Stream? I'm actually quite new to writing out to files, so If you could elaborate or point me towards a resource that would be extremely helpful. 

Also note that you must catch a FileNotFoundException and an IOException-Anyone who uses this advice in the future.

Comment: Nothing to do with Stream. Like I said your btn action is only writing to the XSSFCell but not the XSSFWorkbook. `schedule.write(out);` only executed once in your code and that is when your application creates the stage and scene.

Comment: @Jeremy O'Handley: You seems not have understand when `start` runs. It runs **once** when the stage is created. It creates the workbook sets the value 25,  creates the button, sets the button on action handler and writes the `schedule.xlsx`. Then it shows the scene on the stage and is done. On button click only the `btn` `OnAction`  runs, nothing else. The `start` does not run again. Why should it?

Comment: @Axel Richter that makes sense. If I want these actions to occur later than the start method I should put the in a different class or in main?

Comment: @Jeremy O'Handley: What is wrong with Gino's answer? For me it looks correct. You can programming your code so that it makes actions you need whenever you want. Either on button click, as here. But also somewhere on program flow. But of course you needs to know how the program flows. But learning this is nothing what can be handled in one question here. There are tutorials or courses for.

Comment: @ Axel Richter
I think I understand now. Bear with me because I'm new to JavaFX and ApachePOI and FileOutputStream. Other things I've done have no used these. Basically, I want to be able to edit that file in various different ways and at different times. My question is, if I have already used FileOutputStream which creates the file, can i use that later without overwriting the file? Or do i use FileInputStream?

Comment: @Jeremy O'Handley: "I want to be able to edit that file in various different ways and at different times.": Don't think that way. A `Excel` **file** is nothing what can be "edited" like a text file. One need opening the `Workbook` from the file using `InputStream` (maybe `FileInputStream`). Then on can do what is needed with the `Workbook` in memory. If done then the `Workbook.write` method will **always** write the whole workbook to an `OutputStream` (maybe `FileOutputStream`).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but, your point is that you need to have a null value when your application run again, or what?

If your issue is just, "when open be clean", you can put a simple jquery on your code, or js and clean the input.